# Cannot get "/tinder/cards" route but getting "/" route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, postman

This below code is my first react application. After running server.js. After entering "http://localhost:8001/" I got HELLO!!. I expected after entering "http://localhost:8001/tinder/cards" url on chrome and postman too I get following error.

error message: "Cannot GET /tinder/cards".

this is my server.js file.

````
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import Cors from 'cors'
import Cards from './dbCards.js'


// App Config
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001
const connection_url = 'mongodb+srv://admin:0tRkopC1DKm4ym4V@cluster0.iw73w.mongodb.net/tinderDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json())
app.use(Cors())
app.use('/',router);

// DB Config
mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

// API Endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("HELLO!!"))
app.get("/hello", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Oooooooo!!"))

app.post("/tinder/cards", (req, res) => {
    const dbCard = req.body
    Cards.create(dbCard, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data)
        }
    })
})

app.get("/tinder/cards", (req, res) => {
    Cards.find((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
})

// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on location: ${port}`)) ```
````

Comment: You have a line `app.use('/', router)`, where is the `router` object declared?

Answer (score 1):

try this in your `app.get('/tinder/cards')` section:

```js
// Doing it the Asynchronous way

app.get('/tinder/cards', async (req, res) => {
  try { // Trying for getting the cards
    const allCards = await Cards.find(); // Getting the cards
    res.status(200).send(allCards); // Sending the cards
  } catch (error) { // Catching the error
    res.status(500).send(error); // Sending the error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `cards` with `card` in the URL. [Have a look at the image for the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYcSF.jpg)